# ISupportIncrementalLoading GridView within a ScrollViewer fires LoadMoreItemsAsync continuously

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I've used the ISupportIncrementalLoading collection to bind some large data sets to several GridViews in my app. They work really well when the scroll is provided by the GridView control.

However, on one of my pages I've got some content above the GridView that I want to be part of the scroll.

Here's the XAML:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="RootScroller" VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <!--static content here--> 
    </Grid>        
    <GridView Grid.Row="1"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled">                    
    </GridView>
  </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

**The when loading the page, the LoadMoreItemsAsync is fired over and over again.** I know this same issue can happen when the GridView is inside of a StackPanel because the GridView never get's a proper height. Perhaps the layout I have is causing the same issue? Any thoughts on how I can get the dynamic loading to work in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

> I know this can happen when the GridView is inside of a StackPanel because the GridView never get's a proper height. Perhaps the layout I have is causing the same issue?

No. If you put a `GridView` inside a `StackPanel` as you known, the `GridView` never get its proper height. It will lead the `GridView` not scroll according to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33091862/scrollviewer-not-working-on-a-grid).

> This is because the height of a stack panel is infinite. Since the height and the width are basically inherited by the container, the scroll viewer never has a reason to scroll as it is already allows to grow to infinite size.

But for your scenario, the `ScollerViewer` can work well. I tested your code, the `ScrollerView` can work  but the data cannot be fetched virtualization, it will load all the data when loaded the `GridView`.

> The when loading the page, the LoadMoreItemsAsync is fired over and over again.

If you have a `GridView` inside `ScrollViewer` , the `LoadMoreItemsAsync` will be fired over and over again until the data load completed.  The `ScrollerViewer` defeats virtualization. For the reason please see the description about  [UI virtualization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/optimize-gridview-and-listview#ui-virtualization) .

> Some panels allow child elements unlimited space, examples being ScrollViewer and a Grid, with auto-sized rows or columns. When a virtualized ItemsControl is placed in a panel like that, it takes enough room to display all of its items, which defeats virtualization. Restore virtualization by setting a width and height on the ItemsControl.

According to the article, your solution is easy, restore virtualization by setting a height for the `GridView`. You will find another issue after height set, the content above the `GridView` cannot scroll together with `GridView` since it is in different row with `GridView`. You need to put them inside same container. Here comes the sample code I suggested which you can test.

```
<ScrollViewer
    x:Name="RootScroller"
    HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled"
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
    VerticalScrollMode="Enabled">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock x:Name="tbCollectionChangeStatus" />
        <ListView x:Name="lvEmployees" Height="800">
           ...
        </ListView>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

You can also set the height in code behind.

Comment: I've set my page up with your XAML and it's not working for me. I don't see how the ListView in your example can scroll via the RootScroller if it's at a fixed height. That example just results the ListView content being cut off with no way to scroll it.

Comment: @Scott, I upload a minimize [demo](https://github.com/sunteenwu/CVirtualization) you can do further testing. Actually we have two scrollviewers in this scenario, one is outside for scrolling the 'content' and ListView, one is inside ListView for scroll the virtualization data. We cannot put the 'static content' inside the ListView for scrolling. We can just scroll between the `static content` and ListView. So if the height of 'content' and 'ListView' less than the application view, you will not see the bar. Deep comprehend the concepts I mentioned above can help you more.